# Send arraylist of object to next activity Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to send an arraylist of object users to the next activity. I tried many options on the internet but non of them worked. It shouldn't be that hard, but it just does not seem to work like I want it. The application just closes.

I read that I had to made **User** implement Parcelable.

Here is what I'm trying to do in my **First Activity**:

```
  btnFindMatch.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,PeopleActivity::class.java)
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("userlist", users)

            //intent.putExtra("userlist",users)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
```

My user class :

```
package nl.duoapp.trashtoss.classes

import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable

data class User(val name : String, val hobby: String, val description : String, val birthdate : String, val gender : String, val lat : String, val long : String) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString()
    ) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<User> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): User {
            return User(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<User?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

To read the data I use the follow:

```
        users = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("userlist")
```

The application crashes before it reaches the next activity.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: replace `this` with `activityname.this`  some time context get crashed the application, as you said that you did't reach at `getParcelableArrayListExtra`. it seems like context has a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TODO()` function is designed to always crash. You have to replace it with something. In this case, you need to implement the `writeToParcel` function to write all the properties to the Parcel in the same order.

Edit based on EpicPandaForce's answer.
Or just use `@Parcelize` so you don't have to implement it yourself. Your whole class can be just this:

```
@Parcelize
data class User( 
    val name : String, 
    val hobby: String, 
    val description : String, 
    val birthdate : String, 
    val gender : String, 
    val lat : String, 
    val long : String) : Parcelable
```

Comment: What should I put in the writeToParcel method? I don't know what that does

Comment: This method is there for you to define how you convert the data from your class into a Parcel (which is a data container). You already defined how to get that data back out of a Parcel in you second constructor. However, the other answer mentions you can just use `@Parcelize`, which I hadn't heard of before. That will make this way easier. See my edit.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. If I delete the whole class, and add what you wrote it said I must implement the following methods : writeToParcel and describeContent

Comment: From what I've read, that's an IntelliJ bug, and it will still compile and run. Is it not complaining about `@Parcelize`?

Comment: Aah I see, It does work indeed :). But i'm curious, how do I fix it the other way, so I don't see red lines in my code :P?

Comment: I Fixed it! Thank you for your help :) I made my function like this :  override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest!!.writeString(name)
        dest!!.writeString(hobby)
        dest!!.writeString(description)
        dest!!.writeString(birthdate)
        dest!!.writeString(gender)
        dest!!.writeString(lat)
        dest!!.writeString(lat)
    }

Comment: You could write `dest?.apply{ writeString(...) writeString(...) etc.}` to make that a lot less ugly.

Comment: You can actually just type `Parcel`instead of `Parcel?` because it's a platform type. And we know Parcel will never actually be null.

Answer (score 2):

```
override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

No surprise. The default implementation of `TODO` is `throw NotImplementedError()`.

You should consider using `@Parcelize` rather than implementing the constructor(Parcel), writeToParcel, and describeContents. It generates their implementation for you.

Comment: I don't get it, can you explain it further?

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#parcelable-implementations-generator